# How edit functionality update its value in frontend in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write edit functionality in angularjs.  It almost has done. But the value is not updated in view part.  Can anyone help? My code is given below
Am using ng-repeat="book in books"

Html

```
 <li ng-click="delegate.editPost()">Edit</li>
 <div ng-show="showEditPost">
   <div ng-click="delegate.savePost()">Save</div>
   <p ng-if="showEditPost==false">{{book.text}}</p>
   <div ng-if="showEditPost == true">
      <textarea >{{edit.text}}</textarea>
   </div>
 </div>
```

controller

```
    editPost:function(){
            $scope.showEditPost=true;
            $scope.edit=angular.copy($scope.books);
        },
       save:function(){
            var Obj = {
                text: $scope.edit.text
            }
            editService.edit( Obj,this.onSuccess, this.onFailure);
        },

    onSuccess:function(){

            $scope.showEditPost=false;
            angular.copy($scope.edit,$scope.books);
        }
```

Comment: I cant see `ng-repeat` in your html

Comment: put your proper code

Comment: ng-repeat="book in books"

Comment: please give me a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making it too complicated. But instead of working with entire arrays, you should be passing the index and working with individual elements. Here is a simple demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.books = [{
    "text": "Book 1"
  }, {
    "text": "Book 2"
  }];
  $scope.showEditPost = $scope.books.map(function(_) {
    return false;
  }); // populating array with `false` values
  
  $scope.editPost = function(index) {
    $scope.showEditPost[index] = true;
    // edit is now an element and not an entire array 
    $scope.edit = angular.copy($scope.books[index]);
  }
  $scope.savePost = function(edit, index) {
    $scope.books[index] = edit;
    $scope.showEditPost[index] = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<!-- 
`track by $index` is added to allow repetition/duplicates
-->
  <div ng-repeat="book in books track by $index">
    <!-- passing index with `$index` -->
    <button ng-click="editPost($index)">Edit</button>
    <!-- editing only an individual box by using index -->
    <p ng-if="!showEditPost[$index]">{{book.text}}</p>
    <div ng-if="showEditPost[$index]">
      <button ng-click="savePost(edit,$index)">Save</button><br>
      <!-- `ng-model` is added to allow modification -->
      <textarea ng-model="edit.text">{{edit.text}}</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I have one doubt. What about the service call?

Comment: @yazhini I don't have your service, or logic for it, so you need to adapt this code for yourself. Just put it into `savePost` function call and modify everything as you need it. _This was just an example/demo after all_

Comment: How to use id instead of index?

Comment: @yazhini I don't see why you need to use an ID, you are modifying a row. But if each book has an `id` property, you can pass it as a parameter with `your_function( book.id )`.

Comment: You are correct. But now am struggling with that only. How To pass the book id as parameter with my function

Comment: instead of using the index, I need to pass the book id as the parameter for edit and save the post

Comment: @yazhini in my example `edit` is always a copy of the selected `book` with the given index (a row). The use of `id` is not needed.

Comment: My scenario is no need to take the copy of the book. I need to edit only the text. Because within the book there are a lot of key and values. so I need to take the copy of only text.

Comment: @yazhini then you would edit only text (?), what's so difficult about that? you would need this instead: `$scope.edit = angular.copy($scope.books[index].text);`, then change `"edit.text"` to `"edit"`, where it shows up